# How to prevent Foxycart Action on submit with empty field?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, field, action

Hollo All,

I am creating a form that exports data on submit to an ecommerce solution called Foxycart.  I would like the form to only proceed onto foxycart when the date field is entered however it currently only displays the alert message then proceeds to the action on the form.  Does anyone have advice on how to prevent the action on submit?  please see code below:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["delivery-date-info"]["Delivery_Date_is"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Date must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>



<form name="delivery-date-info" action="https://austin-roman.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

            <div class="add-to-bag">
                <label for="datepicker-example3"></label> 
                <input id="datepicker-example3" type="text" name="Delivery_Date_is">
                <input type="submit" id="datepicker-example3" type="text" class="button-add"> 

            </div>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using FoxyCart's default "sidecart" approach (as of v2.0), you'll need to use FoxyCart's own event system, [described here](http://wiki.foxycart.com/static/redirect/javascript). For your specific example, it might look like this:

```
var FC = FC || {};
FC.onLoad = function () {
    FC.client.on('cart-submit', function(params, next) {
        if (validateForm()) {
            next();
        }
    });
};

function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["delivery-date-info"]["Delivery_Date_is"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Date must be filled out");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here's an alternate approach that'd be a bit more flexible, would allow more than one product form per page, and also shows a little more what's going on:

```
var FC = FC || {};
FC.onLoad = function () {
    FC.client.on('cart-submit', function(params, next) {
        $element = $(params.element);
        if (
            $element.attr('name') == 'delivery-date-info'
            && $element.find('[name="Delivery_Date_is"]').length > 0
            && !$element.find('[name="Delivery_Date_is"]').val()
        ) {
            alert('Date must be filled out');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
};
```